# New route returns me to the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

**[Update]** Code is little canged because I realized that I need more generation pictures for one school (one for each generation) so associations are different now.

I have a *School* model with *GenerationPicture*:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :city
  has_many :sclasses
  has_many :users, through: :sclasses
  has_many :generation_pictures

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :icon_url, length: { maximum: 100 }

end

class GenerationPicture < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :generation, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, uniqueness: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  belongs_to :school

end
```

This is my *generation_pictures* controller:

```
class GenerationPicturesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        find_city
        find_school

        @generation_picture = @school.generation_pictures.new
    end

    def create
        find_city
        find_school

        @generation_picture = @school.generation_pictures.new(generation_picture_params)

        if @generation_picture.save
            redirect_to generation_picture_path(@generation_picture)
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit
        find_city
        find_school
        find_generation_picture
    end

    def update
        find_city
        find_school
        find_generation_picture

        if @generation_picture.update(generation_picture_params)
            redirect_to generation_picture_path(@generation_picture)
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    private

    def generation_picture_params
        params.require(:generation_picture).permit(:generation, :image)
    end

    def find_city
        @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
    end

    def find_school
        @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    end

    def find_generation_picture
        @generation_picture = @school.generation_pictures.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

When I try to access the page for new picture I'm returned to the index page and console shows no errors.

Here are routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  # prevedene rute
  get "/pocetna"          => "welcome#index", as: "index"
  get "/korpa"            => "carts#new", as: "new_cart"
  get "/poslato"          => "carts#success", as: "success"

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  get "/prijava"   => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "/prijava"  => "sessions#create"
  get "/odjava"    => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
  delete "/odjava" => "sessions#destroy"

  #resources :users do
  #  resources :photos
  #end

  # Gradovi
  get "/gradovi" => "welcome#index", as: "cities"
  get "/gradovi/novi" =>  "cities#new", as: "new_city"
  post "/gradovi" => "cities#create"
  get "/gradovi/:id" => "cities#show", as: "city"
  get "/gradovi/:id/uredi" => "cities#edit", as: "edit_city"
  patch "/gradovi/:id" => "cities#update"

  # Škole
  get "/gradovi/:city_id" => "schools#index", as: "schools"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/nova-skola" => "schools#new", as: "new_school"
  post "/gradovi/:city_id/" => "schools#create"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id" => "schools#show", as: "school"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id/uredi" => "schools#edit", as: "edit_school"
  patch "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id" => "schools#update"

  # Tabloi
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/novi" => "generation_pictures#new", as: "new_generation_picture"
  post "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "generation_pictures#create"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/:id" => "generation_pictures#show", as: "generation_picture"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/:id/uredi" => "generation_pictures#edit", as: "edit_generation_picture"
  patch "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "generation_pictures#update"

  # Razredi
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "sclasses#index", as: "sclasses"
  post "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "sclasses#create"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/dodaj" => "sclasses#new", as: "new_sclass"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:id" => "sclasses#show", as: "sclass"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:id/uredi" => "sclasses#edit", as: "edit_sclass"
  patch "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:id" => "sclasses#update"

  # Učenici
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id" => "users#index", as: "users"
  post "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id" => "users#create"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/dodaj" => "users#new", as: "new_user"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/:id" => "users#show", as: "user"
  get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/:id/uredi" => "users#edit", as: "edit_user"
  patch "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/:id" => "users#update"
  delete "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/:id" => "users#destroy"

  resources :city
  resources :carts

end
```

This is the form partial:

```
<% if controller.action_name == "edit" %>

    <%= form_for [@city, @school, @generation_picture], url: generation_picture_path(@city, @school, @generation_picture), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

        <% if @generation_picture.errors.any? %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    <% @generation_picture.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                        <li><%= msg %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.label "Fotografija:" %>
        <%= f.file_field :image, class: "input-field" %>

        <%= f.label "Generacija:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :generation, class: "input-field" %>

        <%= f.submit "Pošalji", class: "btn btn-default" %>

    <% end %>

<% else %>

    <%= form_for @generation_picture, url: school_path(@city, @school), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

        <% if @generation_picture.errors.any? %>
            <div class="errors alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    <% @generation_picture.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                        <li><%= msg %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.label "Fotografija:" %>
        <%= f.file_field :image, class: "input-field" %>

        <%= f.label "Generacija:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :generation, class: "input-field" %>

        <%= f.submit "Pošalji", class: "btn btn-default" %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**[Update]** Rake routes output

```
new_generation_picture GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/novi(.:format)                         generation_pictures#new
                        POST   /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id(.:format)                                    generation_pictures#create
     generation_picture GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/:id(.:format)                          generation_pictures#show
edit_generation_picture GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/tablo/:id/uredi(.:format)                    generation_pictures#edit
                        PATCH  /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id(.:format)                                    generation_pictures#update

            schools GET    /gradovi/:city_id(.:format)                                                     schools#index
         new_school GET    /gradovi/:city_id/nova-skola(.:format)                                          schools#new
                    POST   /gradovi/:city_id(.:format)                                                     schools#create
             school GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id(.:format)                                           schools#show
        edit_school GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id/uredi(.:format)                                     schools#edit
                    PATCH  /gradovi/:city_id/skola/:id(.:format)                                           schools#update
```

**[Update 2]** Current routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  get "/korpa"            => "carts#new", as: "new_cart"
  get "/poslato"          => "carts#success", as: "success"

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  get "/prijava"   => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "/prijava"  => "sessions#create"
  get "/odjava"    => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
  delete "/odjava" => "sessions#destroy"

  scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi' }) do
    resources :cities, path: 'gradovi', except: [:index, :destroy] do
      scope(path_names: { new: 'nova-skola', edit: 'uredi' }) do
        resources :schools, path: 'skola', except: [:index, :destroy], shallow: true do
          scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
            resources :sclasses, path: 'razred', except: [:destroy] #, shallow: true
            scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
              resources :users, path: 'ucenik'
            end
          end
          scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi'}) do
            resources :generation_pictures, path: 'tablo', except: [:index, :destroy]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  resources :carts, except: [:new] # defined at top

end
```

Comment: Sounds like it's working correctly.  Is the `GenerationPicture` record created?

Comment: I guess it is, cause I can see it with ``GenerationPicture`` from Rails console, if you mean that?

Comment: If you mean ``generation_picture`` in the choosen school then no, it's not created (returns ``nil``).

Comment: So the record exists, but it's not showing under `@school.generation_pictures` ... have you tried `@school.reload` first? If that doesn't work, can you examine `GenerationPicture.last` and make sure (a) it's the record that should've been created and (b) the `school_id` column has a value.

Comment: No, ``@school.generation_pictures`` doesn't exist, ``school`` has ``generation_picture``. I checked now, and ``school_id`` column is nil in last record (there's only one in database) - what should I do?

Comment: Huh.  Can you try adding `@geneation_picture.school = @school` before the `@generation_picture.save` ?  It's not a final solution but would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I can't get to the create action, it redirects me to the index page right after trying to access new view.

Comment: can you add your `rake routes` output for the `school` and `generation` groups of routes?

Comment: @Eric I've added them at the end of the post.

Comment: When you say "index page" you mean it redirects to `redirect_to school_path(@city, @school)` ?  That's what happens after a successful save...

Comment: It never redirected me to ``school_path`` because I haven't created any record beside the first one. It returns me to the ``index`` action of ``welcome`` controller, index page of the website.

Comment: Can you add the `school` routes, too?

Comment: @Eric , added them too.

Comment: I updated the post, read the notice at the top. I'm still running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of routes overriding others, such as:

```
get "/gradovi/:id" => "cities#show", as: "city"
# vs.
get "/gradovi/:city_id" => "schools#index", as: "schools"
```

and

```
post "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "generation_pictures#create"
# vs.
post "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id" => "sclasses#create"
```

and

```
get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:id" => "sclasses#show", as: "sclass"
# vs
get "/gradovi/:city_id/skola/:school_id/razred/:sclass_id" => "users#index", as: "users"
```

Rails can't tell whether a number is supposed to be `:id` or `:city_id`, it just sees a number. Likewise, configuring the same URL to go to multiple controller actions will result in disappointing behavior.

I think a good first step is to simplify your route definitions with nested resources and [translated paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  # prevedene rute
  #
  # another duplicate of root_path:
  # get "/pocetna"          => "welcome#index", as: "index"
  get "/korpa"            => "carts#new", as: "new_cart"
  get "/poslato"          => "carts#success", as: "success"


  get "/prijava"   => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "/prijava"  => "sessions#create"
  get "/odjava"    => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
  delete "/odjava" => "sessions#destroy"

  # Gradovi
  scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi' }) do
    resources :cities, path: 'gradovi', except: [:index, :destroy] do
      # don't create multiple routes to 'welcome#index', 
      # use root_url or root_path
      # get '/gradovi', to: 'welcome#index', as: 'cities', on: :collection

      # Škole
      scope(path_names: { new: 'nova-skola', edit: 'uredi' }) do
        # use root_url here for 'welcome#index', too
        resources :schools, path: 'skola', except: [:index, :destroy] do
        # Tabloi
        scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi'}) do
          resources :generation_pictures, path: 'tablo', except: [:index, :destroy]
        end
        # Razredi
        scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
          resources :sclasses, path: 'razred', except: [:destroy]
          # Učenici
          scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
            resources :users, path: 'ucenik'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # You already have `resources :cities` as 'gradovi' above:    
  # resources :city
  resources :carts, except: [:new] # defined at top

end
```

This is going to change your route helper names that you're using elsewhere in your code, but your routes should be much cleaner now. You should also look into the [`shallow` routing keyword](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), because nesting this many deep just to get to your users (for example), is not a great style.

There's no reason why getting a list of students for a class has to include the city in the URL, and nobody wants to type `new_city_school_sclass_user_path(@city, @school, @sclass)`, so organize your urls better. It doesn't affect your associations or any app functionality, just the route names and URLs. I suggest putting `shallow: true` on `schools`:

```
scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi' }) do
# Gradovi
  resources :cities, path: 'gradovi', except: [:index, :destroy] do
    # don't create multiple routes to 'welcome#index', 
    # use root_url or root_path
    # get '/gradovi', to: 'welcome#index', as: 'cities', on: :collection

    # Škole
    scope(path_names: { new: 'nova-skola', edit: 'uredi' }) do
      # use root_url here for 'welcome#index', too
      resources :schools, path: 'skola', except: [:index, :destroy], shallow: true do
        # Razredi
        scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
          resources :sclasses, path: 'razred', except: [:destroy] #, shallow: true
          # Učenici
          scope(path_names: { new: 'dodaj', edit: 'uredi'}) do
            resources :users, path: 'ucenik'
          end
        end
        # Tabloi
        scope(path_names: { new: 'novi', edit: 'uredi'}) do
          resources :generation_pictures, path: 'tablo', except: [:index, :destroy]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives you a list of routes like this:

```
                         root GET    /                                            welcome#index
                     new_cart GET    /korpa(.:format)                             carts#new
                      success GET    /poslato(.:format)                           carts#success
                        login GET    /prijava(.:format)                           sessions#new
                      prijava POST   /prijava(.:format)                           sessions#create
                       logout GET    /odjava(.:format)                            sessions#destroy
                       odjava DELETE /odjava(.:format)                            sessions#destroy
                 sclass_users GET    /razred/:sclass_id/ucenik(.:format)          users#index
                              POST   /razred/:sclass_id/ucenik(.:format)          users#create
              new_sclass_user GET    /razred/:sclass_id/ucenik/dodaj(.:format)    users#new
                    edit_user GET    /ucenik/:id/uredi(.:format)                  users#edit
                         user GET    /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                              PATCH  /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                              PUT    /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                              DELETE /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
              school_sclasses GET    /skola/:school_id/razred(.:format)           sclasses#index
                              POST   /skola/:school_id/razred(.:format)           sclasses#create
            new_school_sclass GET    /skola/:school_id/razred/dodaj(.:format)     sclasses#new
                  edit_sclass GET    /razred/:id/uredi(.:format)                  sclasses#edit
                       sclass GET    /razred/:id(.:format)                        sclasses#show
                              PATCH  /razred/:id(.:format)                        sclasses#update
                              PUT    /razred/:id(.:format)                        sclasses#update
   school_generation_pictures POST   /skola/:school_id/tablo(.:format)            generation_pictures#create
new_school_generation_picture GET    /skola/:school_id/tablo/novi(.:format)       generation_pictures#new
      edit_generation_picture GET    /tablo/:id/uredi(.:format)                   generation_pictures#edit
           generation_picture GET    /tablo/:id(.:format)                         generation_pictures#show
                              PATCH  /tablo/:id(.:format)                         generation_pictures#update
                              PUT    /tablo/:id(.:format)                         generation_pictures#update
                 city_schools GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola(.:format)            schools#index
                              POST   /gradovi/:city_id/skola(.:format)            schools#create
              new_city_school GET    /gradovi/:city_id/skola/nova-skola(.:format) schools#new
                  edit_school GET    /skola/:id/uredi(.:format)                   schools#edit
                       school GET    /skola/:id(.:format)                         schools#show
                              PATCH  /skola/:id(.:format)                         schools#update
                              PUT    /skola/:id(.:format)                         schools#update
                       cities POST   /gradovi(.:format)                           cities#create
                     new_city GET    /gradovi/novi(.:format)                      cities#new
                    edit_city GET    /gradovi/:id/uredi(.:format)                 cities#edit
                         city GET    /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       cities#show
                              PATCH  /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       cities#update
                              PUT    /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       cities#update
                        carts GET    /carts(.:format)                             carts#index
                              POST   /carts(.:format)                             carts#create
                    edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                    carts#edit
                         cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                         carts#show
                              PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)                         carts#update
                              PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                         carts#update
                              DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)                         carts#destroy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this helped me a lot! But what to do with POST routes; when I send the form for creating school, I get the error ``no route matches [POST] "/gradovi/1"`` ? Is there a way to automatically do this instead of adding POST route for every case separately?

Comment: In my example, the route helper for creating a school is `city_schools`, so you wouldn't POST to `/gradovi/1`, which actually matches `city_path(@city)` and won't create a school. By default, POST is only used for creating objects, so you'll never supply an ID in a POST request. 

You should use `city_schools_path(@city)`, which would POST to a URL like `/gradovi/123/skola`.

Comment: Thanks, everything works great now, but I still have the problem with the users; I have ``school_users`` path but with it I lose the track of ``sclass`` (parent of the ``users`` defined via ``through`` association) - is there a way to make it to be ``new_sclass_user`` instead of ``new_school_user`` path?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your routes look different than mine ones; you have ``new_sclass_user`` route and I don't have it. I don't understand how this happened.

Comment: Double-check your routes again.

Comment: I checked them more than twice - I've used the last example you posted in your answer.

Comment: I posted my current **routes.rb** file.

Comment: I realized where was the problem; in your example you forgot to enclose ``users`` resources inside ``classes`` resources, it works now - thanks for the help :)